# Regex - match a pair of repeated characters after space or beginning of line

Tags: regex

I've been trying to learn regular expressions for some time now, and sometimes I run into some stuff I find hard to understand.

Early today I was trying to match a pair of repeated characters after space or beginning of line, so I first found a way to match space or beginning of line: `(^|\s)`

Then, to match a pair of (alphanumeric) characters: `(\w)\1+`

Both work very well, but when I put them together `(^|\s)(\w)\1+`, it just doesn't work.

Do you know why that is wrong, and what is the best way to achieve what I want?

By the way, I'm using [this website](http://regexpal.com/) to test my expressions.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(?:^|\s)(\w)\1
```

Problem is you are using capturing group for `(^|\s)` and that becomes `\1` and `(\w)` becomes `\2` therefore your regex doesn't work.

`(?:..)` is non-capturing group hence `(\w)` remains `\1` (first capturing group).

Answer (score 0):

`(^|\s)(\w)\1+, it just doesn't work`

@anubhava gave you the answer.
This commented example might help as well.

```
 ( ^ | \s )        # (1), BOL or whitespace
 ( \w )            # (2), Word character
 \1+               # backreference to group 1 (BOL or whitespace)


 ( ^ | \s )        # (1), BOL or whitespace
 ( \w )            # (2), Word character
 \2+               # backreference to group 2 (Word character)
```